# Should we pay for buddhist teachings or retreats?

Tags: money

Good evening everyone.

I am a newcomer to buddhism, although i have been reflecting on and practicing many concepts very much ressembling to buddhism for a decade.

I understand that monks and nuns need to make a living, however it seems to be a tendency to ask for money during teachings. As someone who grown up around christians, i am used to giving money on a volunteer basis but i might just be totally wrong about this. Of course there are always expenses and it is normal that we participate.
I am however very sceptical when people ask for too much money, especially when they are supposed to teach us.

In my life, i have encountered greed many times, and i have been acting with greed in my mind on several occasions. It took me a few years to understand it was wrong and i don't consider myself so greedy anymore.

Retreats are also extremely expensive in some monasteries.
I am however far from a saint and still an outsider to buddhism in general, so my words might be missplaced.

It is my belief that money is indeed the root of all evil as some christians like to say. It tooks me years to realize it. So what do you think about paying for teachings, retreats, etc? Is this common practice in buddhism?

Comment: And see also -- [Are there Theravada meditation retreats that allow one to work for room and board?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/10644/254) -- (can't add more than 5 items in the list of duplicates above).

Comment: "Should we pay..." wasn't really asked so far, allthought it might be included in other questions answers. To answer short: if someone offers something for a certain exchange and one wished to receive it, it's proper to pay the deal, otherwise it would be against ones good observation of precepts. If right to wish something material back for Dhamma is the offerers issue and his Kamma an certain good not to approve, but wrong to demand something someone is not willing to give, although if not praiseworthy at all. Maybe good to do not mix pay and charge, one's deeds, that of another.